# persisting a JSON string to OrientDB using Datanucleus without enhancer

Tags: json, datanucleus

I am trying to persist a json string (myobject.toJson() gives me my object in json) to orientdb. But I am hitting with "org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "java.lang.String" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found."

How do I get around this?

Thanks
Gopi

here is error stack

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type ("java.lang.String") is not that of an entity but needs to be for this operation
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.assertEntity(JPAEntityManager.java:1330)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.persist(JPAEntityManager.java:529)
>       at com.x.myclass.receive(Myclass.java:90)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   Caused by: org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "java.lang.String" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
>       at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.assertClassPersistable(ObjectManagerImpl.java:5464)
>       at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAEntityManager.assertEntity(JPAEntityManager.java:1326)
>       ... 9 more

Comment: so why are you passing a String to em.persist?

Answer (score 0):

The Datanucleus plugin is poor supported, why don't use OrientDB object interface directly?

Comment: we want to use datanucleus as an abstract layer to support multiple persistence layers.

Comment: Using the JPA interface of OrientDB it's a good enough way to be standard and generic, isn't? You could switch to another JPA implementation.

Comment: probably we could. But datanucleus provides an abstraction above RDBMS, non-RDBMS (like document base databases like Mongodb, orientdb, couchdb) and like any other file based systems too. I doubt JPA can  work universally. Is it?

Comment: If you use 2 JPA impl like OrientDB and Hibernate you can switch implementation for free. But OrientDB JPA implementation is not 100% compliant, so some changes could be needed.